# How to make a Label disappear when button is pushed?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I am currently working on a very basic quiz app.

The user will have the option of 4 choices.

If the correct button is pressed, the hidden label (LabelEnd) will show "Correct" and automatically go to the next randomized question.

If they push the wrong button, the hidden label will then read "Wrong" and stay on the same question.

My question is: how do I make it so that the label is hidden again after 1 second, regardless if it is correct or wrong?

```
func Hide() {
    LabelEnd.hidden = true
}

func UnHide(){
    LabelEnd.hidden = false
}

@IBAction func Button1Action(sender: AnyObject) {
    UnHide()
    if(CorrectAnswer == "1"){
        LabelEnd.text = "Correct!"
        RandomQuestions()
    } else {
        LabelEnd.text = "Wrong"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UIView animate method with duration where you can set your interval time.

Like this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
     LabelEnd.hidden = false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide your label after 1 second this way:

```
var dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.LabelEnd.hidden = true
})
```

And you can change time as per your need.

And you can use it this way:

```
func Hide() {
    var dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.LabelEnd.hidden = true
    })
}

@IBAction func Button1Action(sender: AnyObject) {
    UnHide()
    if(CorrectAnswer == "1"){
        LabelEnd.text = "Correct!"
        Hide()

    }
    else{
        LabelEnd.text = "Wrong"
        Hide()
    }
}
```

One more way to do that is you can use `timer` for that as shown in below code:

```
var timer = NSTimer()

func Hide() {
    LabelEnd.hidden = true
    timer.invalidate()  //You can remove timer here.
}

func UnHide(){
    LabelEnd.hidden = false
}

@IBAction func Button1Action(sender: AnyObject) {
    UnHide()
    if(CorrectAnswer == "1"){
        LabelEnd.text = "Correct!"
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Hide"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)


    }
    else{
        LabelEnd.text = "Wrong"
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Hide"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    }
}
```